# how to use Routing System sidenav in Library Argon Dashboard PRO React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

sidenav.js

```
if (type === "route") {
        if (href) {
            returnValue = (
                <Link href={href} key={key} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                    <SidenavItem
                        name={name}
                        icon={icon}
                        active={key === itemName}
                        noCollapse={noCollapse}
                    />
                </Link>
            );
        } else {
            returnValue = (
                <NavLink to={route} key={key}>
                    <SidenavItem name={name} icon={icon} active={key === itemName}/>
                </NavLink>
            );
        }
    } else if (type === "divider") {
        returnValue = <Divider key={key} light={darkSidenav} />;
    }

    return returnValue;
});
```

I am using a [argon-dashboard-react](https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard-react/#/admin/index) free template for my application from creative-tim URL: https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard-react/#/admin/index

I want use Collapse(nested routes) of Creative Tim (Argon Dashboard 2) using ReactJS.

routes.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    type: "route",
    name: "My class",
    key: "myclass",
    route: "/myclass",
    icon: <ArgonBox component="i" fontSize="14px"><img height={20} src={myclass} alt="Icon"/></ArgonBox>,
    component: <Myclass />,
  },
  {
    type: "route",
    name: "My calendar",
    key: "mycalendar",
    route: "/mycalendar",
    icon: <ArgonBox component="i" fontSize="14px"><img height={20} src={calendar} alt="Icon"/></ArgonBox>,
    component: <Mycalendar />,
  },
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Resources",
    icon: <ArgonBox component="i" fontSize="14px"><img height={20} src={resources} alt="Icon"/></ArgonBox>,
    key: "resources",
    collapse: [
      {
        name: "School Resources",
        key: "school resources",
        icon: <ArgonBox component="i" fontSize="14px"><img height={20} src={brand22} alt="Icon"/></ArgonBox>,
        route: "/resources/schoolresources",
        component: <SchoolResources />,
      },
      {
        name: "My Resources",
        key: "my resources",
        icon: <ArgonBox component="i" fontSize="14px"><img height={20} src={brand22} alt="Icon"/></ArgonBox>,
        route: "/resources/myresources",
        component: <Myresources />,
      },
    ],
  },
```

I try use React Hook (useState) but not displayed as desired. how to fix at file sidenav.js